# how to integrate a simple menu in python

Tags: python, user-interface, interface, menu

This is my current HiLo game, I want to integrate a menu with 4 options, 1. read csv file 2. play game 3. show results and 4. exit, any help is appreciated.
Because I don't know where to start.

```
 import\
    random
n = random.randint(1,20)
print(n)
guesses = 0

while guesses < 5:
    print("Guess the number between 1 and 20")
    trial = input()
    trial = int(trial)

    guesses = guesses + 1

    if trial < n:
        print("higher")
    if trial > n:
        print("lower")
    if trial == n:
        print("you win")
        break

if trial == n:
    guesses = str(guesses)
    print("Congratulations it took" + " " + guesses + " " + "tries to guess my number")
if trial != n:
    n = str(n)
    print("Sorry, the number I was thinking of was" + " " + n + " ")`enter code here`
```

Comment: Starting with printing out a menu and figuring out what kind of user input to accept. For example, print out the menu with the options the user has. Then take input. If the input doesn't match any the options you presented, continue to loop, and ask the user for input again.

Comment: so kinda like creating a decoy where it shows the user some text but behind the scenes the number inputs just lead to functions?

Comment: Yep @goshag44, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your game loop inside a menu loop, and all the code for csv file, etc. inside these loops...

However, it is surely preferable to learn a little bit about functions, in order to organize your code a little bit:

Here, I placed your game loop inside a function, and also created functions for the other options; right now, they only print what they should be doing, but as you add features, you will fill this with code.

```
import random


def read_csv():
    print('reading csv')

def show_results():
    print('showing results')

def play_game():
    n = random.randint(1,20)
#    print(n)
    guesses = 0 
    while guesses < 5:
        print("Guess the number between 1 and 20")
        trial = input()
        trial = int(trial)

        guesses = guesses + 1

        if trial < n:
            print("higher")
        if trial > n:
            print("lower")
        if trial == n:
            print("you win")
            break

    if trial == n:
        guesses = str(guesses)
        print("Congratulations it took" + " " + guesses + " " + "tries to guess my number")
    if trial != n:
        n = str(n)
        print("Sorry, the number I was thinking of was" + " " + n + " ")    


while True:

    choice = int(input("1. read csv file 2. play game 3. show results and 4. exit"))
    if choice == 4:
        break
    elif choice == 2:
        play_game()
    elif choice == 3:
        show_results()
    elif choice == 1:
        read_csv()
```