# Tried to add a value to a while condition, but it doesn't go back

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a guess game just for testing while loops, but I want an option so who plays can try again.

I tried to make it work again by just adding some "lifes" which in case is (b) in the code.

```
b = 3

while b > 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    if guess == 9:
        print("You won!")
        break
    else:
        b -= 1

if b == 0:
    print("You lost m8")
    again = input("Wanna try again? [y/n] ")
    if again == "y" or "Y":
        b += 3
```

I expected it to go back to the while, just because the code added some "lifes", since it was again at something greater than 0.

Comment: You need two while loops: one for repeating the game, and one for the game itself. Look at this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173820/how-to-integrate-a-simple-menu-in-python/55173952#55173952

Comment: @ReblochonMasque No, they just need to adjust their current loop

Answer (score 2):

Just adjust your loop accordingly:

```
b = 3
while b >= 0:
    if b == 0:
        print('You lost!')
        while True:
            again = input('Want to try again? [y/n] ').lower()
            if again != 'y' and again != 'n':
                pass
            else:
                break
        if again == 'n':
            break
        else:
            b += 3
    else:
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if guess == 9:
            print('You win!')
            break
        else:
            b -= 1


Guess: 7
Guess: 6
Guess: 4
You lost!
Want to try again? [y/n] 3
Want to try again? [y/n] lol
Want to try again? [y/n] y
Guess: 3
Guess: 2
Guess: 1
You lost!
Want to try again? [y/n] n
```

Comment: @Passarinっぱさりーん `while True:` means **forever**. Unless you use the statement `break`, that `while` would never stop.

Comment: @EnderLook it does have a `break` too.

Comment: @perennial_noob, I know, I just was explaining to Passarin what is a `while True` and how to "break" it. Maybe my "that" confuses you but I wasn't talking about your `while`, I was talking in general, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and simple fix would be **add an additional `while`**:

```
b = 3

while b > 0:
    while b > 0:
        guess = int(input("Guess: "))
        if guess == 9:
            print("You won!")
            break
        else:
            b -= 1

    if b == 0:
        print("You lost m8")
        again = input("Wanna try again? [y/n] ")
        if again == "y" or "Y":
            b += 3
```

Adding another `while` will solve your problem. You may run out of lives during an iteration of the loop but the statement `b > 0` is only checked at the beginning of each iteration so if you choose `y` or `Y`, `b` will be increased by 3 and the code will keep running, if you don't choose `y`, `b` will stay at 0 and so the code will stop.

But if you are looking to improve your code you should modify the input section. If you write anything that isn't `y` or `Y` the code stop, even if you wrote `No` or `:)`. Instead you should make a `while true` or something similar until you receive a positive (`y`, `Y`, `yes`...) or negative (`n`, `N`, `no`...) answer and not nonsense stuff (like `:)`, `XD`...)

Comment: Oh that's it! Thanks a lot, much appreciated! Now I _understand_

Comment: If that answers your questions you may think in accepting this answer. If not, you are free of choosing another answer as accepted or not to choose any of those until finding the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the game block to a function and call the function when required:

```
b = 3
def play():
    while b > 0:
        guess = int(input("Guess: "))
        if guess == 9:
            print("You won!")
            break

        else:
            b -= 1
    return None
play()


if b == 0:
    print("You lost m8")
    again = input("Wanna try again? [y/n] ")
    if again == "y" or "Y":
        b =3
        play()
```